# Laravel 4 leftJoin mySQL statement not returning correctly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am a little frustrated with my inexperience with Laravel's query builder.  I have a mySQL statement that is working fine to compare two nearly identical tables for any missing rows.  However the Laravel version isn't working for me.

Basically I have two tables test_1 & test_2, each with columns: id, name & color.  I am trying to list any missing rows. Here is the table structure:

table: test_1

[image: test_1]

table: test_2

[image: test_2]

Here is the mySQL (this works fine), it returns: '4 | birgit | yellow'

```
SELECT a.*
FROM test_1 a
LEFT JOIN test_2 b ON b.name = a.name
WHERE b.id is NULL
```

Here is what I believe ought to be the Laravel equivalent (not working - it returns an object with null values for each of the three properties):

```
$test = DB::table('test_1')
    ->leftJoin('test_2', 'test_2.name', '=', 'test_1.name')
    ->where('test_2.id', null)
    ->get();
```

My next step is to compare for where the name is the same but the color is different between the two tables and this is not working either.  Any help you have is much appreciated, as always.  Thanks!

```
$test = DB::table('test_1')
    ->leftJoin('test_2', 'test_2.name', '=', 'test_1.name')             
    ->where('test_2.color', '!=', 'test_1.color')
    ->get();
```

UPDATE:  Using the DB::raw method (below) works as expected.

```
$test2 = DB::select( DB::raw('SELECT a.* FROM test_1 a LEFT JOIN test_2 b ON b.name = a.name WHERE a.color != b.color'));
$test3 = DB::select( DB::raw('SELECT a.* FROM test_1 a LEFT JOIN test_2 b ON b.name = a.name WHERE b.id is NULL'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get NULL values because, well, those are the values when there isn't a match in table_2.  You need to manually alias and select the columns from table_1.

```
$results = DB::table('table_1')
            ->leftJoin('table_2', 'table_2.id', '=', 'table_1.id')
            ->where('table_2.id')
            ->select('table_1.id AS id', 'table_1.name AS name', 'table_2.color AS color')
            ->get();
```

Comment: So close and yet so far!  Thanks for the nudge.  It worked perfectly... much appreciated!